# Text Wrapping for tooltips isn't working when set via resource

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have an application with a `stackpanel` of `stackpanels` - essentially one vertical `stackpanel` with several horizontal ones in it, containing various controls. Each horizontal `stackpanel` has a tooltip describing what that collection of controls does. Because some of these tooltips are long, I wanted to set a default (in this vertical stackpanel) max width for tooltips and enable text wrapping.

If I set this manually, it works as expected

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
  <StackPanel.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip MaxWidth="400">
      <TextBlock Text="Lots and lots of really long text that should overflow and show if this thing works." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
      </ToolTip>
   </StackPanel.ToolTip>
     ...other controls...
</StackPanel>
```

However, when I try to set it as a resource on the main vertical `stackpanel`

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="300" />
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
  </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

The max width is correct, but word wrapping doesn't happen. There are other setters in there, but even when I comment them all out the problem remains - the tooltip text is being cut off because there's no wrapping.

What have I missed?

Comment: Can you post your xaml file? I can't reproduce the issue, it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Because Textblock is an inner element of the Tooltip, you should add an inner style for it.

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="300" />
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```